# Working with tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, wamp

I'm used to work with WAMP and I find it very easy to understand. Now I need to start up with JSP and I've downloaded Tomcat7. 
I installed it together with JRE and Eclipse but i just can't get how it works.
I placed my project in /webaps/ but when i access the local host, it shows just the WAMP projects (placed in /www/ folder).

How exactly is this Tomcat server used and is there a way to combine it with WAMP so it can be easier to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you stopped your wamp server?

Comment: If I stop the WAMP server, I can't find the localhost any more

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat listens by default on port 8080. Make sure that you're opening http://localhost:8080. The port number is configureable in Tomcat's `/conf/server.xml`.

To get Tomcat and WAMP (specifically: Apache HTTPD) to work togeher, use [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/). Or use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), it comes with integrated Tomcat next to WAMP as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you start it up? The startup script is usually in TOMCAT/bin/startup.bat or Tomcat/bin/startup.sh on a unix environment.

Answer (score 0):

Like @BalusC said: You tomcat is normally running at port 8080.

But also important is that you compiled your java classes of your project.
Your eclipse project is not autocomplied.

Most simple way: export you project as `*.war` in the `/webapps` folder. than your tomcat should autodeploy your project.

But you could also use the Tomcat6 IDE for eclipse where you can start your project by "Run As"/"On Server"